# How to find First & Last Line using Regex?

Tags: regex, find, line, notepad++

```
    2011-08-31   62,756 1400177600.pptx
    2011-09-01  129,988 1403639000.pptx
    2011-09-05  364,884 4003557200.pptx
    2011-09-05  88,484 4400167700.pptx
    2011-09-01  37,908 4400169200.pptx
```

above is original text.. i want to covert this

```
    <contents>
    2011-08-31   62,756 1400177600.pptx
    2011-09-01  129,988 1403639000.pptx
    2011-09-05  364,884 4003557200.pptx
    2011-09-05  88,484 4400167700.pptx
    2011-09-01  37,908 4400169200.pptx
    </contents>
```

I need to find first & last line using Regex on Notepad++

How can I find first and last line ?

Comment: Ummm, why do you need a regex for this? Just scroll to the top, type that opening tag, hit enter, scroll to the bottom, hit enter and type that closing tag.

Comment: I suppose you could always record a macro.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. **You do not use a regex just to delete lines using a text editor!**  `sed -e 1d -e '$d' file` will give you the file without the first and last lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this works, but I used this in Textmate:

```
^(?:(?<![\f\n\r])(?:.*))(?=[\f\n\r])|^.*(?![\f\n\r])$
```

The first part,

```
^(?:(?<![\f\n\r])(?:.*))(?=[\f\n\r])
```

finds the first line. Not sure about Notepad++, but (annoyingly) Textmate matches ^ to any start of line. So I had to check for the text (.*) that is followed by a form feed, newline or return ([\f\n\r]), and is not preceded by the same.

The second part,

```
^.*(?![\f\n\r])$
```

was easier. It just finds a start of a line (^) with the text (.*) that is not followed by a end of line.

**EDIT**: after re-reading OP's post I get that it should have the beginning tag and closing tag. To do that, you could use the first part of the expression for the beginning tag and the last expression for the end tag.

Comment: on an additional note, if Notepad++ does not do what I said about ^, and ^ only matches the beginning of the file, then you could try ^.*(?=[\f\n\r])|(?<=[\f\n\r]).*$

Comment: Yes, `^` and `$` behave the same way in Notepad++ as in TextMate.

Comment: attention: this won't work in notepad++ versions prior to 6.0.0, as those don't support searching for newlines, so make sure that you are running an up to date version